# Get the count of pool

Tags: elixir, httpoison

I’m using HTTPoison and Hackney pools:

```
:hackney_pool.child_spec(:start, [checkout_timeout: ..., max_connections: 100]),
:hackney_pool.child_spec(:trigger, [checkout_timeout: ..., max_connections: 100]),
:hackney_pool.child_spec(:result, [checkout_timeout: ..., max_connections: 100])

...

HTTPoison.get('...', [...], [
...,
hackney: [pool: :start]
])
```

Is there any way to сatch the number of running/queuing connections and monitor them in live?
Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the [get_stats/1](https://github.com/benoitc/hackney/blob/master/src/hackney_pool.erl#L20) function on `:hackney_pool`. This returns a [proplist (keyword list in Elixir)](https://github.com/benoitc/hackney/blob/master/src/hackney_pool.erl#L629L633) with:

```
[ {:name, "pool_name"},
  {:max, 100},
  {:in_use_count,  19},
  {:free_count, 81},
  {:queue_count, 0}
]
```

Then you can use the [Keyword.fetch/2](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Keyword.html#fetch!/2) function to get the `:in_use_count` value, which will tell you the active connection count. I'm not 100% sure on how you'd monitor it though.

Comment: For the default pool, you can do

```iex> :hackney_pool.get_stats(:default)```